# if entry has specific category, show specific html block

Tags: filter, conditional, relatedto

I have entries, which can have several categories.
These categories are in different categorie groups.

Now if i show an entry page, i want to display i certain html block
based on a specific category, the entry has or not.

i tried this, but its not working, i think i get the relatedTo thing wrong:

```
//i loop through all the categories in my group

{% for category in craft.categories.group('catGroup1') %}

//the i go to the section my entries are in and relate that to the categories i want to filter

{% set categoryListings = craft.entries({
  section: 'kelims',
  relatedTo: [
    { targetElement: category, field: 'filterThisCategory' }
  ]
}) %}

//if the entry has this category

{% if categoryListings|length %}

  display some html block

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you set the entry type in the `kelims` section. Could you tell me more about your `filterThisCategory` field? A screenshot of the field settings would help. 
I'm also unsure I understood correctly what you try to achieve. You just want to output some HTML if the entry you're currently viewing has a specific category, right?

Comment: My approach above was a wrong one. Regarding your last question, @nstCactus, yes, thats what i mean.
I eventually fount the solution, with the help of these pages:
https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/categories-fields.html#templating,
https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/categories.html#querying-categories

{% if entry.myFieldHandle.id('48, 49, 50, 51').exists() %}
 do this 
{% else %}
 do this
{% endif %}

myFieldHandle is the fieldHandle of the Category Group, where the categories i am searching for, are in.

Comment: @nstCactus, so your hint with the "exists()" was the right one, but i needed to add the ids.

Answer (score 1):

`craft.entries()` returns an `EntryQuery`. You must then [execute the query](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/element-queries.html#executing-element-queries) with one of those methods:

- `one()`
- `all()`
- `count()`
- `exists()`

In your case, I think `.exists()` is the best choice: `{% if categoryListings.exists() %}`

Edit: You may also have to execute your category query with `{% for category in craft.categories().group('catGroup1').all() %}`. See https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/categories.html#querying-categories.

Comment: i tried your answers and hints, but no luck. maybe my approach with the craft.entries() is not the right one.